# Laravel PUT Request fails : Parse Error: The response has a duplicate "Content-Length" header

Tags: laravel, postman, laravel-routing, put

## Context

Using Postman I send a `PUT` HTTP request to my Laravel API.

## Expected behavor

Postman should show "test" as a response.

## Actual behavior

Postman shows the error **"Parse Error: The response has a duplicate "Content-Length" header"** as a response.

## The route

I have defined in `api.php` the following route:

```
Route::put('/test', function(Request $request) {
    return 'test';
})->name('test');
```

This route exists: indeed, `php artisan route:list` returns the following...

> PUT      | api/test                       | test                            | Closure                                                                 | api

## The request

In Postman I have defined the following request (the URL is in the shape of: `https://<laravel site>/api/test`):

[image]

[image]

[image]

## What I've tried to do

According to the Laravel docs, `_method = PUT` should be sent when a HTML form pointing to a `PUT` route is sent with `POST` because it's incompatible with `PUT`. Normally here, since I use JSON, it's not the case. But even though it could be useless, I've put it, in case I was wrong.

Moreover I've explicitly specified `application/json` as value for `Content-Type` and `Accept`. Also I've specified `XMLHttpRequest` for make the server know it's an XHRequest.

Finally, there is the CSRF token and the Sanctum token (Bearer Token). I don't know if their values are correct but thanks to other requests not shown here, I know I'm authenticated using Fortify so normally the Sanctum token value may not be used (because of the standard authentication cookie session is defined by Fortify) ; for the CSRF token maybe it's the same.

## Question

Why doesn't Laravel simply show "test"?

## Clues

NGinx configuration could be the root cause of this problem. Digging deeper...

Answer (score 1):

Just because I can't see the url. Do you have '/api/test'?

Comment: Yes, I am going to specify it

Comment: I'm not sure what causes the multiple Content-Length error. Do you have multiple Content-Length headers in Postman?

Comment: I don't see them in the response, no :-)

Comment: Is there a Content-Length in your request?
EDIT: Make sure your hidden headers are shown.

Comment: Of course, Postman calculates the request length and put the result in the request's header "Content-Length"

Comment: If so, I have no idea.

Comment: I was told by someone of my team that our NGINX server has a configuration problem that would cause this error:) But ty for your help Simon;)